# Firefox Placeholder Before CSS selector not working

Tags: css, sass, css-selectors, placeholder

I'm using the latest firefox 30.0. I'm trying to insert a red font awesome star before the placeholder of required fields. I got this working in Chrome no problem but I'm having issues with FF and.

Here's a codepen illustrating my issue - http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BLibw

My markup:

```
<input placeholder="Address" data-required required id="id_street" name="street" type="text" />
```

My CSS(sass):

```
[data-required] {
    &::-webkit-input-placeholder::before { font-family: fontAwesome; content:'\f005  '; color: $color-red; }
    &::-moz-placeholder::before { font-family: fontAwesome; content:'\f005  '; color: $color-red; } /* firefox 19+ */
    &:-ms-input-placeholder::before { font-family: fontAwesome; content:'\f005  '; color: $color-red; } /* ie */
}
```

Note: Turns out IE is giving me a hard time too.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is not with the placeholder, but the fact that you are trying to apply a `::before` pseudo-element to an `input`, which isn't supported cross-browser because it's not defined within the standards. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587669/css-after-pseudo-element-on-input-field/4660434#4660434).

Since this obviously depends on the form element being `[data-required]` (although it's not clear to me why you need a `data-required` attribute in addition to the standard `required`), you *may* need to add an extra `span` element after the `input` and style that element using a sibling selector, rather than using a pseudo-element.