# Adding "*" to input Placeholder using CSS

Tags: css

Not able to add Asterisk before Placeholder even using placeholder definition Demo is Given Below

HTML:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Asterisk Before Placeholder"/>
```

CSS:

```
input::-webkit-input-placeholder:before {
  content: '*';
}
input:-moz-placeholder:before { /* Firefox 18- */
  content: '*'; 
}
input::-moz-placeholder:before {  /* Firefox 19+ */
  content: '*';
}
input:-ms-input-placeholder:before {  
  content: '*';
}
```

See the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/shakeelkoper/9wsh13pf/)

Comment: Similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24377777/firefox-placeholder-before-css-selector-not-working).

Answer (score 0):

Please try this using Javascript:

```
var asterisk = "* ",
    inputList = document.getElementsByTagName("input");

for(i=0; i < inputList.length; i++) {
     inputList[i].placeholder = asterisk.concat(inputList[i].placeholder);
}
```